# How would you implement Role based authorization for Trello clone?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, backend

I am fairly new to backend development with .net 6. I am trying to implement a Trello Clone whereby the user that created a Trello Project can give access to other users to join the project and create and edit the cards. How do i conceptually go about doing this? I just need an idea not looking for implementations. The users have to be in the db. All users must be authenticated.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate on [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, the question is so general about "role based authorization" that you might want to narrow it down a bit. What have you tried/considered? What leads you to ask the question here and not on your favourite search engine? What blocks you?

Answer (score 0):

The key words you're going to want to start researching are OWIN (for authorization) and Membership Roles. OWIN allows you to utilize third party IDPs as well as have a local database of users (if that's what you want). So, people could log in with their google credentials, for instance.

Additionally, you'll need a way to track which users have access to which boards. Assuming you're using a relational database, this will be a custom database table.

Lastly, you'll want to send an invitation email with a special link that includes a key (think GUID or some other globally unique format) in that custom table. That way, when the user clicks the link and logs in, you can mark the user as having accepted the invitation.

If you had some code or something you could post, I'm sure you'd get a better, more straight-forward answer, but your question was very general.